# Cannot read property session of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to implement LDAP active directory. When i try to pass in user credential through the front end, I'm getting an error *Cannot read property 'session' of undefined*. I think i'm not passing in session to AD. I'm able to Authenticate user when i hard code user credential.

How can I solve this?

```
path            = require('path'),
logger          = require('morgan'),
ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory'),
bodyParser      = require('body-parser'),
dotenv          = require('dotenv'),
passport        = require('passport'),
session         = require('express-session');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
  resave            : true,
  secret            : 'kool',
  saveUninitialized : true,
  cookie            : {}
}));


const Strategy = { 
  url: 'n/a',
  baseDN: 'n/a',
  username: 'n/a',
  password: 'n/a'
}
const ad = new ActiveDirectory(Strategy);
let user;

  app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
user.session;
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const loginSuccess = await ad.authenticate(username, password, (err, auth, res, req) => {
  if(err) {
   console.log(`Yo invalid credentials: ***** ${JSON.stringify(err)} ]******* `);
   return 
  } 
  if(auth) {
    req.session.loggedin = true;
    req.session.username = username;
    res.redirect('/index')
    console.log(`User ${username} is Authenticated`);
  } else {
    // res.send('Auth Failed')
    console.log(`Auth failed`)
    res.redirect('/')
  }
  res.end();
  });
});

app.get('/index', function(request, response) {
  if(request.session.loggedin) {
    response.send(`Welcome back, ${request.session.username}`)
    res.render('index', {title: 'Main Page'})
  } else {
    response.redirect('/')
  }
  response.end();
})
```

Comment: Your issue is comming from `let user;` and then `user.session;`. What do you need those for, since the `user` variable doesn't seem to be used anywhere?

Comment: Just trying out different options. Totally agree with you on that, user variable is not being use anywhere.

Comment: Solved! @BoyanHristov

Comment: Nice! Was the above mentioned `user` variable the only issue? If not, it's perfectly ok to answer your own question, perhaps others will find it useful